# Is there a way to build wordpress based CMS using RDF data

Tags: php, wordpress, sparql, rdf

I want to build wordpress based CMS using RDF (for persons) data as well as mySQL data (form news blogs ets). Data is store and retrieved from Sparql endpoint, and shown as a text on WP site i.e 
1) it will retrieved all information regarding person from sparql endpoint and publish it on WP site with nice GUI. 
2) Also it has editorial part in which person will be able to edit his content and it will be saved in RDF dataset. 
3) On later stages it will be connected to other sites so that person will not need to update his data on every site.

I am new to all this so my question is, will it be possible in Wp?? and if so how I will go through it. In my head for News,blog etc Wp will be used and for publishing/retrieving and updating Persons I have to create my own CMS. Am i going in right direction??

Comment: yes, it's possible - but clearly, the question is too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could consider is to use [Carbon LDP](https://carbonldp.com/), a Linked Data Platform. *(Disclaimer: I am product-related staff, but this answer is certainly viable for your goal and relevant to your question.)*

The Standard (free edition) of Carbon LDP will give you a RESTful API and an RDF native file-store database suitable for small - medium (loosely speaking) apps. Carbon also has a JavaScript SDK which allows you to easily work with the REST API and JavaScript model objects of just about any shape. For example - just invent the JSON representing your Person, and Carbon will do the rest (converting everything to RDF behind the scenes when you save the object, and the converting back to the JavaScript object when you load). Of course you still get your SPARQL endpoints and all of the goody-good benefits of Linked Data. Carbon just makes it easier by abstracting a lot of the complexities away and providing a document-oriented approach to RDF that is more familiar to the everyday web developer.

You would need to develop whatever visual widgets are necessary to create the forms for data entry and the display output on a WordPress page. You could build those widgets using standards-based Web Components for example (e.g. using [Stencil](https://stenciljs.com/) compiler) or whatever you're comfortable with (like vanilla JS / CSS / HTML). Basically, those widgets will just be calling Carbon's REST API (via the Carbon LDP JS SDK) to read and write data. Then you can leave it up to WordPress to do all the rest of the stuff that it does so well. The reason why I suggest Web Components is because that'll just give you simple HTML tags that can be used like any other HTML tag on a WordPress page to create widgets where you want them. The related JS can be injected into your theme's head using the WordPress recommended enqueue approach for themes or child themes.

You might also choose to code some of the stuff in theme, child theme, or a WordPress plugin if you find that it helps your workflow (there's always a few different ways to "skin the cat").

Comment: Hi Cody thanks alot I will look into it but what if I want to develop a plugin having some sparql queries to display stuff of people..  Will it be a good approach too??

Comment: I do not see any reason why using a WordPress plugin that uses SPARQL should not be a good approach. I am personally not familiar with any helper libraries or tools for RDF/SPARQL and PHP, but I would venture to guess they're out there. I'm not familiar just because I do not do much PHP development, but you should look for something that might ease the task. Otherwise, it might be a bit of a hassle to parse the binding set results you get back from SPARQL query. Although the results format you can get back also depends on what database you use, I guess - and what it supports.